# Erro ao tentar efetuar calculo em campos da mesma tabela em update mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `convenio`;
CREATE TABLE `convenio` (
  `codigo`      int(8)        DEFAULT NULL,
  `cpf`         varchar(11)   NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Nome`        varchar(35)   DEFAULT NULL,
  `valor`       decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `valorfinanc` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dif`         decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `codger`      varchar(6)    DEFAULT NULL,
  `cpf0`        varchar(11)   DEFAULT NULL,
  `data`        timestamp     NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status`                    int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`cpf`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

O que preciso:

Um update que faça:

```
UPDATE SET dif = valor - valorfinanc WHERE cpf = cpf
```

Estou tentando da seguinte forma:

```
    $listaconv  = mysql_query ("SELECT 
                                  * 
                                    FROM financeiro 
                                      ORDER BY nome",$convenio_conn) 
                                          or die (mysql_error());
                                             while($row = mysql_fetch_array($listaconv)){
                                               $VarConvCodigo         = $row[0];
                                               $VarConvCPF            = $row[1];
                                               $VarConvNome           = $row[2];
                                               $VarConvValor          = $row[3];
                                               $VarConvCodTotvs       = $row[4];
                                               $VarConvCPF0           = $row[5];
                                               $VarConvData           = $row[6];
                                               $VarConvValorFinanc    = $row[7];
                                               $VarConvDifAvancFinanc = $row[8];
                                               $VarConvStatus         = $row[9];

    $gera_divergencia = mysql_query ("UPDATE convenio 
                                        SET difavancfinanc = '$VarConvValor'-'$VarConvValorFinanc' WHERE cpf = '$VarConvCPF'",$convenio_conn)
                                           or die (mysql_error());
}
```

Só que não esta fazendo o calculo corretamente e os valores que aparecem no  `dif` não tem nada a ver a conta, o que estou fazendo errado ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você já verificou se os valores que estão vindo no $row estão corretos?

Tente efetuar um var_dump no inicio do seu while para checar.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($listaconv)){
    var_dump($row);
    die;
...
```

Se estiver tudo correto com os dados que deseja efetuar a subtração, sugiro que você cria uma variável que receba a subtração, para evitar cálculos na instrução SQL e evitando qualquer problema futuro de performance. Fora que gerando a variável, você consegue verificar posteriormente o valor que foi gerado, assim podendo fazer uma conferência antes de dar o UPDATE no banco de dados.

Ex:

```
$difavancfinanc = $VarConvValo - $VarConvValorFinanc;
```

Comment: Realmente não estava passando corretamento com o  var_dump($row); achei o erro, era erro de sintaxe, obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Sempre que vou tratar de um array eu uso o var_dump para fazer a verificação do que estou tratando... sempre acontece erro de sintaxe ou mesmo de incompatibilidade de tipos. Feliz por poder contribuir!

Answer (score 2):

Tenho duas possíveis soluções:

A primeira é que você está fazer uma string subtraindo outra string, isso pode estar dando conflito. Então tire as aspas das variáveis $VarConvValor e $VarConvValorFinanc do update:

```
UPDATE convenio SET difavancfinanc = $VarConvValor - $VarConvValorFinanc WHERE cpf = '$VarConvCPF'
```

Ou criar uma variavel php antes e setar ela direto na query:

```
$diferenca = $VarConvValor - $VarConvValorFinanc;
$gera_divergencia = mysql_query ("UPDATE convenio SET difavancfinanc = $diferenca WHERE cpf = '$VarConvCPF'",$convenio_conn) or die (mysql_error());
```